# Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2008 missing Add method

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to use Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2008 (.NET 3.5).

I can find it in the Add New Item and it does all it should do(created classes etc.)

But when I try to add a new entity into the database like:

```
myModel.students.Add(newStudent);
```

I cannot find Add() method under students object at all!

Is that because I haven't referenced to some nedded dlls?
Or Entity Framework doesn't support Add method in VS2008(.NET 3.5)

To me, it's so weird. I never met this situation before and don't think it should happen.

---

**Update 1:**

I also tried to use LINQ2SQL, but still there are no Add, or AddObject/AddEntity methods. There are no anything like AddXXXX() methods.

What happened?

Comment: What type `myModel` has? Can you add its class definition to question? Also it would be nice to know type of `students`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Hi SB, thanks to your reply. myModel is a class inherited from System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext and students are a list of System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<student> and finally, student is inherited from System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject. Cheers

Comment: As Kasper suggested, use `myModel.AddToStudents(newStudent)`. I also suggest you to update version of EF you are using

Comment: thx mate. However, it's a part of requirements that I cannot change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ObjectContext` instead and call `AddToStudentSet(newStudent).`

```
myModel.AddTostudentSet(newStudent);
```

You are using an old version of Entity Framework. Back then Entity Framework came bundle with System.Data and wasn't a stand alone library. Instead of having Add/AddObject methods on the DbSet/EntitySet the tool generated add methods directly on the ObjectContext and named them according to the name of the entity.

So an entity called `Student` would result in a method called `AddToStudentSet`

Newer versions of EF dropped this approach and instead generate these methods directly on the DbSet.

Comment: There are nothing like AddXXX methods under students.........That's why I said it's so weird....

Comment: Cool! Found that method directly under the data context object. Hi Kasper, could you please explain why it happens? It doesn't make sense to me. Is it because the old version of ET?

Comment: Oooops, not ET, it's EF. haha

Comment: Yes, older versions of EF were constructed a bit differently. Newer versions of EF will have either the AddObject or Add methods directly on the DbSet<T>.

Comment: thx mate :). What are the differences between AddObject and AddToXXXSet()? When should I use which?

Comment: When you are using old versions of the framework you are forced to use AddToXxxSet, in newer versions it has been replaced with Add or AddObject. I'm not sure from which version of .NET and EF that they switched to the new approach.